# MacBookPro9,2 does not recognize drive as bootable after clean Install

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, install, ssd

The original hard drive stopped working, so I got a new SSD (Crucial MX300, 275GB, part number [CT275MX300SSD1](https://www.crucial.com/products/ssd/crucial-mx300-ssd)) to put into the MacBook Pro and make a clean install of macOS.

Installation of High Sierra using an USB drive looked like it went through well, but when the MacBook Pro rebooted, it got to a screen where it just shows a flashing folder icon with a question mark inside.

After that failed, I tried a second time using Network Recovery and installed Mountain Lion. Same flashing folder icon after reboot. NVRAM reset did not fix the issue.

After wiping the drive once again, I immediately ran a volume check using Disk Utility and it told me that the volume was damaged.

Output of `diskutil verifyVolume disk1s2`:

```
Started file system verification on disk1s2 Macintosh SSD
Check file system
Checking Journaled HFS Plus volume
Checking extents overflow file
The volume Macintosh SSD could not be verified completely
Error: -69845: File system verify or repair failed
Underlying error: 8: POSIX reports: Exec format error
```

So maybe the issue lies on the SSD itself?

Comment: What exact error do you get in disk utility?

Comment: @X_841 I added the output of diskutil to the question.

Comment: Someone here on AD had a very similar question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/251160/diskutil-verifyvolume-posix-reports-exec-format-error/251262 Maybe try that?

Answer (score 2):

It turned out the hard drive cable was faulty. I found a couple of Q&A's on the net (like https://de.ifixit.com/Antworten/Ansehen/356610/Hard+Drive+SATA+cable+failing+related+to+the+battery+brackets) that highlighted the issue and so i decided to give a new cable a try. I ordered a new one, replaced it and now everything works without any issues.